# Matlab multiply matrix M * P(n-1)

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Lets say I have a 3x3 matrix and a 3x1 vector, I want to multiply my matrix `A` with vector `P` multiple times.

```
A=[0 0.3 0.5; 0.8 0 0.5; 0.2 0.7 0] * P=[1; 1; 1]
```

I want to multiply the answer of this with `P` for `N` times.

Now I can do this by hand but I am being forced to use Matlab and it is giving me a headache.

Cheers

Comment: So you mean `(((A*P)*P)*P)....)*P` ? Use a `for` loop

Comment: `A*P` is a 3x1 vector, how do you want to matrix-multiply that with another 3x1 vector?

Comment: Yes, the I want the vector of A*P multiplied again with P. Its for population dynamics.

Comment: My guess is you mean (A^n)P. As Amro explains, the product of a vector and a matrix is another vector...

Comment: I think the answer by @TryHard is what you need, unless you really want something like this for `N=4`, `A*P*P'*P*P'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess, but I think what you want is

```
PN = mpower(A,N)*P0
```

Here `N` is the generation number, `P0` is the initial population vector.

As suggested by @LuisMendo and @DennisJaheruddin, this is equivalent to

```
PN = A^N*P0
```

To elaborate somewhat: at each generation you compute a new population from the old using `Pnew = A*Pold`, that is:

```
 P1 = A*P0                % generation 1
 P2 = A*P1 = A*A*P0       % generation 2
 P3 = A*P2 = A*A*A*P0     % generation 3
```

and so on, such that

```
 PN = (A*A*A*A...*A)*P0     % generation N
    = A^N*P0
```

Comment: Any reason to use `mpower(A,N)` instead of `A^N`? Is it faster?

Comment: @LuisMendo I honestly don't know - should check. I wrote it that way because it reduces confusion (in my opinion) with `A.^N`

Comment: @LuisMendo They should be equivalent according to the [doc](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/mpower.html). --- Personal opinion: Unless you find it uncomfortable, it would be a shame not to take advantage of the single character operator.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my answer, I had to run out :) Try Hard hit the nail and all I can say is thank you! And thank you all for that matter, I really appreciate it.